# Hadoop counters - tuning and optimization

Tags: optimization, hadoop, cloudera, performance

I just wrote my first hadoop job. It processes many files and generates multipleoutput files for each input file. I am running it on a two node cluster and it takes about 10 minutes for my largest input set. Looking at the counters below, what are the optimizations I can do to make it run faster? Are there any specific indicators which one should look for in these counters-

[image]

Version: 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2

Map task Capacity:20

Reduce task Capacity:20

Avg task per node:20

Comment: Another interesting fact is that the reducer is not outputting anything to HDFS since the output records are zero. Are you writing to a secondary storage like a database?

Comment: The reducer writes to output files on HDFS. I am not interacting with any secondary storage, then why is the counter 0?

Answer (score 1):

We can see here that most of data reduction happens in the map phase (number of map output bytes is much less then HDFS read bytes, The same about map input records - it is much lower then map input record). We also see that a lot of CPU time spent.  We also see low number of shuffling bytes 
So this job is: 
a) A lot of data reduction is done on Map phase. 
b) The job is CPU bound.

So I think code of mapper and reducer should be optimized. I/O probably is not important for this job.